# Load driving using ULN2003

Tags: schematics, driver

In the attached schematic as shown, I am using [ULN2003](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/389/cd00001244-1795514.pdf) for supplying 2 voltages 28V and 12V to the loads. The loads being connected to the load will be switched on one after another.

The base triggering lines of ULN2003 are converted from differential to single ended using [AM26LS32INSR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am26ls32a.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1637927608685&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.in%252F).

Is this the correct method for supplying voltages to the load using ULN2003?

EDIT1:-

1. S12V0 AND S28V0 are connected to the -VE terminal of 2 different [CCR-33S30T](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/227/teledyne_CCR_33S_CR_33S-2577669.pdf) and [CCS-32N10](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/227/TELDS01524_1-2577868.pdf) mechanical SPDT's.
2. UDIGCON0043 is the PCB. I have shared its schematic below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

R11 and R12 are not necessary, because the 2003 has pull-down resistors built in.  Other than that, the input side looks ok.

Your schematic does not show what the load is or what it is connected to for power, so there is not enough information to answer your question.  Update your question with more information, and I will update this answer.

Comment: I have updated the my question.

Comment: Do you need more information for updating your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The input section looks okay. I don't see any useful connection to COM on the ULN2003A.

If either of the supplies can be disconnected you may wish to connect a 30V or so Zener diode from COM to ground.

Answer (score 1):

1. The drive section for the ULN2003A does not need the pulldown resistors. The ULN2003A already has internal pulldown of about 10K Ohms. The AMS26LS32 is an active pullup/pulldown output, it needs no further load configuration.
2. You have a capacitor (C23) connected from COM to ground, you should remove this as it will delay any initial turn on, for the first supply turned on. You obviously gave some thought to this since you allowed a jumper to connect COM to either 12V or 28V. I'd strongly suggest you remove the capacitor and permanently connect the jumper in the 28V position (or alter the PCB to connect COM to 28V directly).
3. As a suggestion, you could connect 3/4 drivers to each switched port to increase the current capability. Currently you use only one driver of the ULN2003 on each switched port. You may not need the extra current capability, but it spreads whatever current needs you have across the chip. The AM26LS32 is more than capable of driving 3 or 4 inputs in parallel.